# Pyodbc not returning error from SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

Ok, hopefully this is something really silly that I'm overlooking...

I'm using Python 3.7.2 and Pyodbc 4.0.24 on SQL Server 17 (14.0.2002.14)

On my SQL Server I create a table as such:

```
create table test(
    test1 varchar(5)
)
```

But when I try to throw an error (because the table already exists) by executing the same query using pyodbc I don't see any errors returned:

```
def createSQLTable():
    try:
        sql_conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                                    'Server=[SERVERNAME];'
                                    'Database=[DATABASENAME];'
                                    'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
        cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
        sql = '''set nocount on;
           use [DATABASENAME]
           create table test(test1 varchar(5));'''
        cursor.execute(sql)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        sql_conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        sql_conn.close()

createSQLTable()
```

If I run the same TSQL on SQL Server I get the error message:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1 There is already an object named
>   'test' in the database.

So how do I get Python/Pyodbc to throw the same or similar error?

Comment: @Parfait Thanks for the suggestion, that didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: @Parfait No luck with autocommit.

Comment: Remove the redundant `USE` line since you connect directly to this database per connection string.

Comment: @Parfait aha! Figured it was something silly... That works. Submit an answer and I'll mark it correct. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Parfait That does raise another question though... Why would the database redundancy cause the code to complete silently without error? I'm able to get the code working properly now, just trying to fully understand why it worked/didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyodbc does not raise any exception since there is no error with `USE [DATABASENAME]` which is the first transaction type line in your multiple statement query.

Pyodbc like most Python DB-APIs does not support multiple transactional SQL statements in same execution call with some exceptions. Usually only the first query will run.

Consider sending them individually within same `try` block:

```
cur.execute('set nocount on;')
cur.execute('use [DATABASENAME];')
cur.execute('create table test(test1 varchar(5));')
```

Or place lines in a stored procedure and run with either below:

```
cursor.execute("EXEC mystoredProc")

cursor.execute("{CALL mystoredProc}")
```

Or keep only relevant lines as `USE` is unnecessary with database connection specification.

```
cur.execute('''set nocount on
               create table test(test1 varchar(5)
            ''')
```

Comment: "Usually only the first query will run." - Not in my experience. Yes there are some cases where an anonymous code block will fail or produce potentially confusing results (e.g., omitting `SET NOCOUNT ON;` where required) but that is more a function of the ODBC driver than it is of pyodbc itself. pyodbc just passes the SQL command text along to the ODBC Driver Manager and waits for the results to come back.

Comment: Good point @GordThompson. I didn't want to make absolute claims as some multi-line code blocks can run especially TSQL with its batch calls using `GO`. All depends on API, driver, even RDBMS.

Comment: Agreed. And yes in this case (SQL Server) the `use [DATABASENAME]` needs to go first in its own `.execute`, followed by the rest of the anonymous code block.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the necro, but in case anyone else was searching for this, `pyodbc` is not returning an error because it is a getting a non-error related message first, e.g. `(1) rows affected`.  I solved my issue by calling `set nocount on` at the start of the procedure without having to split the calls as per the accepted answer.

Comment: This saved my bacon. Can anyone think of any other such messages that can be outputted but disabled?